# when I am changing the status in dropdown , its changing the value in actual scope in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 4 `(ALL,PAID,UNPAID,PARTIALLY_PAID)` payment statuses and i have to apply filter on these payment statuses based upon the payment status i needs to show the list of invoices.

**Case 1:**

> When current payment status is ALL and i am going to change the
>   payment status to some other status its working fine.

**Case 2:**

> When current status is others than ALL and i am going the change the
>   payement status to some other status its not working fine its changing
>   the changed value in the actual scope object without save.

I wants the change should happen after save.

same is happening for cancel button.

**Code `HTML` part:**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="clientPayment in clientPaymentDetails">
                    <tr
                        style="text-align: center">
                        <td colspan="3" ng-click="showContent(clientPayment.project.name);showData= !showData">{{clientPayment.project.name}}({{clientPayment.project.projectType}})</td>
                        <td colspan="3">{{clientPayment.project.currency}}</td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <!-- <select ng-model="selectedStatus" ng-options="payStatusType.code as payStatusType.type for payStatusType in payStatus"
                            ng-change= "fetchPaymentStatus(selectedStatus, clientPayment.project.name)"></select> -->

                            <select ng-model="selectedStatus" ng-required="true">
                                 <option value="">ALL</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="payStatusType in payStatus" value="{{payStatusType.code}}">{{payStatusType.type}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr
                        ng-show="model.activeRow == clientPayment.project.name && showData" style="text-align: center; 
                        background-color: #5dbbb0 !important; height: 45px; color: white">
                        <th>Invoice ID</th>
                        <th>Invoice Number</th>
                        <th>Invoice Date</th>
                        <th>Invoice Amount</th>
                        <th>Accrual Date</th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>Payment Status</th>
                        <th>Amount Received</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr
                        ng-show="model.activeRow == clientPayment.project.name && showData"
                        style="text-align: center; height: 45px"
                        ng-repeat="invoice in clientPayment.invoiceList |filter: (!!selectedStatus || undefined) && {paymentStatus: selectedStatus}: true">
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceId}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceNo}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceAmount}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.accrualDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.dueDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.paymentStatus}}</td>    
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">{{invoice.amountReceived}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!isEdit">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="isEdit= !isEdit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                        </td>   


                        <td ng-show="isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceId}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceNo}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit">{{invoice.invoiceAmount}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit">{{invoice.accrualDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit">{{invoice.dueDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit"><select ng-model="invoice.paymentStatus">
                        <option  ng-repeat="payStatusType in payStatus" value="{{payStatusType.code}}">{{payStatusType.type}}</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td ng-show="isEdit"><input type="text" ng-model="invoice.amountReceived"></td>
                        <td colspan="2" ng-show="isEdit">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateInvoiceDetails(invoice);isEdit= !isEdit"> <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="isEdit= !isEdit"><i class="fa fa-remove" ></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Controller code:**

```
        $scope.getClients = function() {
            rpmDashboardService.getAllClientsByBusinessUnitId($scope.bu_id)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        $scope.Client_List = response.data;
                    });
        };
    }

    $scope.onClientChange = function(clientId) {
        rpmDashboardService.getAllInvoicesList(clientId).then(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.clientProjects = response.data;

                    var data = angular.copy($scope.clientProjects);
                    $scope.clientPaymentDetails = data;
                    console.log($scope.clientPaymentDetails);
                });
    }

    $scope.showContent = function(name) {
        $scope.model = {
            activeRow : name
        };
    }

    $scope.updateInvoiceDetails=function(invoice){
        if(invoice.amountReceived == null || invoice.amountReceived == "" || invoice.paymentStatus==="" || invoice.paymentStatus==null){
                noty({type:'error',
                    text:'Please enter some amount into Amount Received...'});
        }
        else{
            rpmDashboardService.updateInvoiceDetails(invoice).then(function (response) {

        if (response.status!=200) {
          noty({type:'error',
              text:'Some error occured'});
             }
        else if(!response.data){
             noty({type:'error',
              text:'Invoice can\'t be added'});
             }
        else{

              noty({type:'success',
              text:'New Invoice Details Updated Successfully'});

             }

    });
    }

    }
```

Please find the below screen shots:[for case 1[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkzxJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ng-model to update in same scope and it is immediately gets reflected in your complete  clientPaymentDetails variable.

use below

```
 <select ng-model="paymentSt" ng-change="updateData(paymentSt,invoice)">
     <option  ng-repeat="payStatusType in payStatus" value="{{payStatusType.code}}">{{payStatusType.type}}</option>
 </select>
```

instead of

```
<select ng-model="invoice.paymentStatus">
   <option  ng-repeat="payStatusType in payStatus" value="{{payStatusType.code}}">{{payStatusType.type}}</option>
</select>
```

Use ng-change method to update paymentSt in copy of invoice and put it into scope. When you are saving at that time fetch this invoice (that is copied from original invoice and updated payment status into it) and get paymentStatus and use it to save.